# Install vscode for all users

Tags: visual-studio-code

I updated to the version [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_26#_user-setup-for-windows) where it installs it per user instead of all.

How do I install for all users instead? Do I need to install for each user now?

Comment: You can download the **System Installer** [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/download). I must admit, it wasn't easy to find and only found it by downloading the per user installer and attempting to run it as an administrator

Comment: Related: [Installing extensions for all users](https://serverfault.com/questions/1105754/how-to-install-vscode-extensions-to-all-users).

Answer (score 26):

Look for the **system installer** instead of the **user setup installer**. The system installer will give you the option to:
1. Install for all users
2. Choose a directory.

Download here (oficial page): https://code.visualstudio.com/download

**Can't find it?**  The system installer is below the big blue button to download. You'll see 3 options. The middle option will say **system installer**.

Comment: Is there a significant difference between the two?

Comment: zero in terms of the actual vscode IDE features. it just gives you the option to install to a user only or "deploy" to all users.

Comment: Thanks... but why is this even an option? is there actually a end user requirement for this and why is the user version 'default' and why is it not bundled as an option in the installer... just why?

Comment: Microsoft wants to force all programs to be installed in User/AppData (non-Admin) privileged accounts for IT corporate environments to centrally manage users, i.e., control, restrict, and delete employees easily.  The downside of developer tools installed with "regular" user privileges - not as Administrator ("for all users") - is that BY DEFAULT programs cannot write to protected system file areas, e.g., "Program Files", "Program Files x86", "Windows\System32" and others.  However, developers MUST routinely install their own programs, so such restrictions impede many developer activities.

Comment: @8protons There is a BIG difference between the System Installer and User Installer.  System-level privileges are crucial for fast data science or systems utilities development.  Without full read-write to system areas you can't get work done fast as a developer or data scientist, without constantly raising IT tickets and wasting hours and days waiting for IT managers to approve requests and IT Techs to respond with the installation or modifications required.  Project get delayed seriously waiting for IT to do everything system-related. This is my experience after 25+ years in industry.

Answer (score -1):

Applications that are global are stored in /Applications directory as opposed user specific installation that are installed under Applications under the user home directory. So moving the installed folder to /Applications directory might work.

Comment: You don't want to just "move" the folder, because that will not take care of links, references, or registry entries (on Windows).  It will break many applications.  The applications should be uninstalled from the user account and reinstalled as system administrator.